# Microsoft exchange 2003 export distributional lists

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, exchange-2003

I am running windows server 2003 and running exchange 2003 on it.Is it possible to create a script to export out all the distributional lists.I have searched but not able to find a solution to extract out all the distributional lists from my exchange to an excel?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't people already created programs/solutions for this?

As indicated in this particular link, Manage Engine seems to do what you want it to.

http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/185947-how-can-i-export-exchange-2003-security-distribution-lists-to-excel

https://www.manageengine.com/products/ad-manager/active_directory_group_reports.html

Moreover, if all else fails you can always create scripts based on your requirements although there is a little bit of manual work involved.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555937